# MPI I/O error with MPI_File_seek (no specific subroutine )

Tags: ubuntu, mpi, gfortran, openmpi

currently, I am learning MPI I/O. As consequence, I struggling  with the following example:

```
PROGRAM simple_write 
USE mpi 
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER :: rank, nproc, ierr
INTEGER, ALLOCATABLE :: offsets(:)
INTEGER :: file_handle,my_offset
CHARACTER(len=50) :: outstr 

CALL MPI_Init(ierr) 
CALL MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, nproc, ierr) 
CALL MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, ierr) 
!Delete the existing file
CALL MPI_File_delete('out.txt', MPI_INFO_NULL, ierr) 
CALL MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 'out.txt', MPI_MODE_WRONLY + MPI_MODE_CREATE, MPI_INFO_NULL, file_handle, ierr) 

ALLOCATE(offsets(nproc))

WRITE(outstr,'(A,I3,A)') "Hello from processor ", rank 


CALL MPI_Allgather(LEN(TRIM(outstr)), 1, MPI_INTEGER, offsets, 1, MPI_INTEGER, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)

my_offset =SUM(offsets(1:rank))

CALL MPI_File_seek(file_handle, my_offset, MPI_SEEK_SET, ierr)

CALL MPI_File_write(file_handle, TRIM(outstr), LEN(TRIM(outstr)), MPI_CHARACTER, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, ierr) 
!Close the file
CALL MPI_File_close(file_handle, ierr) 
CALL MPI_Finalize(ierr) 
END PROGRAM simple_write
```

I use gfortran and openMPI.

When I compile it I get the following error:

```
Error: There is no specific subroutine for the generic ‘mpi_file_seek’ at (1)
```

I am not able to understand it. Is something related to an old openMPI version in my Ubuntu distribution?

Thanks

Comment: You are using the wrong type for the offset. It has to be `   INTEGER(KIND=MPI_OFFSET_KIND)`

Comment: This is a fine example of the MPI module stopping you from calling the subroutine wrongly and getting silent and hard to debug errors you would get with `include "mpif.h"`.

Comment: Even better, with `use mpi_f08`, if supported by your MPI implementation, the `file_handle` argument must be wrapped in `TYPE(MPI_File)` and you can't simply pass random integers as file handles.